# Loading a file just once on initialization of python script using Mod_WSGI and Bottle

Tags: python, mod-wsgi, bottle

I am pretty new to Python, Mod_WSGI and Bottle. My main problem is that when the process is run using Mod_WSGI I want it to load a file once on initialization. With running a script in terminal you would just use `if __name__ == '__main__'`

I need it to load the file once on initialization (or when first called) so that any subsequent calls to the process does not require the file to be reloaded. I am unsure of how to do this.

The following code is run whenever someone goes to the recommend page

```
@route('/recommend')
def recommend():
    parser = OptionParser(usage="usage: %prog [options]")
    parser.add_option('-f', '--file', default='data.csv', help='Specify csv file to read item data from.')
    parser.add_option('-D', '--debug', action='store_true', dest='debug', help='Put bottle in debug mode.')
    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
    return res.recommend(request)
```

How do I do the first 4 lines (ones involving parser) just on initialization so that I just need to call the res.recommend() whenever the recommend page is accessed?

Any help is appreciated,
Mo

Answer (score 3):

For daemon mode, place it at global scope in your WSGI script file. That file is only loaded once per process. This would normally be on first request which maps to that application.

For emebedded mode if you modify a WSGI script file it can be reloaded again in same process. In that case, and still even for daemon mode if you wanted to, use a separate script file and use the WSGIImportScript directive to force loading of it on process start.

See:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIImportScript

You will need to know though what process group/application group your WSGI application is running in for it to be loaded in same sub interpreter, so also look at WSGIProcessGroup/WSGIApplicationGroup directives.

Answer (score 1):

Python modules are run only the first time you load them.

Subsequent calls doesn't run the code again

E.g.

mod.py:

```
x = 10
print(x)
```

main.py:

```
import mod #will print 10
mod.x = 5
import mod #nothing is printed. mod.x == 5
```

Comment: Maybe I am not being clear. I don't know how to load the file during initialization. Right now the loading of the file is placed in the code to run whenever a certain path is being called. So currently it is always being reloaded.

Comment: @MoC As I said above: if you run `x = open('file').read()` in the body of your python file, it will just happen the first time you load the module. Maybe I didn't understood what you want...

Comment: @JBernardo I added some code to explain better what I am doing. MOD_WSGI allows for processes/scripts to be run as a Daemon and be called multiple times.

Comment: @MoC You can move the lines to outside the function (as I said above). Then just write `global var_name` for the variables declared as global you need inside the function

Comment: mod_wsgi is designed to run in a multiprocess environment.  Do you want the setup once code to run fewer times than once per apache spawned process?  That may require some extreme cleverness (and it's probably a bad idea)

Comment: I think I got it figured out. Just moved the parts that I wanted initialized once to the .wsgi file.

Answer (score 0):

What you're actually talking about is **caching** the results of the file read.

We'll keep this simple:

```
datacache = None

@route("/someroute")
def someroute():
    if not datacache:
        datacache = do_something_clever_with_file(open("filename"))
    page = make_page_from_data(datacache)
    return page
```

Also, parsing the script input argument in a web method is just bad form. Akin to leaving a wet fish inside your co-worker's desk.

Instead, have a configuration file with the options in there and read the configuration file.

For the braver amongst you, have a look at [a memoizing decorator](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Memoize), turning this into a cache is left as an exercise to the reader, since caching is just memoization with expiry.